# Some letters still persists to appear even if input type for Woocommerce phone number and postcode field is set to 'number'

Tags: validation, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I manage to tweak some stuffs my website' billing checkout field with this code

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_address_fields', 'custom_woocommerce_default_address_fields' );
function custom_woocommerce_default_address_fields( $address_fields ) {
    $address_fields['first_name']['custom_attributes'] = array('maxlength' => 35);
    $address_fields['last_name']['custom_attributes'] = array('maxlength' => 35);
    $address_fields['address_1']['custom_attributes'] = array('maxlength' => 50);
    $address_fields['address_2']['custom_attributes'] = array('maxlength' => 50);
    $address_fields['city']['custom_attributes'] = array('maxlength' => 35);


    $address_fields['postcode']['custom_attributes'] = array('maxlength' => 4, 'type' => 'number' );
    $address_fields['phone']['custom_attributes'] = array('maxlength' => 11, 'type' => 'number' );

    unset($address_fields['company']);
    unset($address_fields['address_2']);

    return $address_fields;
}
```

Notice the two things I made on the postcode and phone number field. I both set specific max lengths to both fields. I also set their input type to 'number' because I notice that letters can also be inputted in these fields which is supposed to be numbers only. But nothing happens as I run this code.

I also tried separating the customization I made for these fields like this one:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );
function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields )
{        
     $fields['billing']['billing_phone']['type'] = 'number';   
     $fields['billing']['billing_postcode']['type'] = 'number';
     $fields['billing']['billing_phone']['maxlength'] = 11;   
     $fields['billing']['billing_postcode']['maxlength'] = 4; 

     return $fields;    
}
```

But the thing is only the *['type'] = 'number'* is the visible change in these two checkout fields. I thought this is okay but as I tested to type all the letters, letter **e** and **r** still persists to appear in postcode and phone field. Is this a bug or is it possible to overcome this issue? I just want to achieve both maxlength and input type = number in those two billing fields.